# RDP to ip address from onclick menuItem #c VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdp

I'm trying to launch a remote desktop session to a specified IP on an onClick function on a menuItem in VS.

```
private void NAMEHEREToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // launch remote desktop to 192.168.0.1
    }
```

So I click NAMEHERE and it should open remote desktop and automatically connect to the IP I've given it. How can I do this? I've googled different things but cant quite find what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rdp+command+line

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can launch the remote desktop program with the /v argument, like this:

```
mstsc.exe /v 192.168.0.1
```

you can also define a port after the IP if needed: 192.168.0.1:1234 for example.

For all arguments, launch it in command propmt:

```
mstsc.exe -?
```

Answer (score 0):

and to start the process:

```
// launch remote desktop to 192.168.0.1
var ipAddress = "192.168.0.1";
var pinfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("mstsc.exe");
pinfo.Arguments = "/v " + ipAddress;
Process.Start(pinfo);
```